# Mysql end value of curdate monthname function

Tags: mysql

Good day, so i know you can create a select statement and views easily, and do a

```
 select curdate() from accounts
```

and then end it as a table name

```
 select curdate() as demodate from accounts.
```

But how can i do this.

```
 select month(curdate()) as monthname(curdate()),
 month(curdate()-1) as monthname(curdate()-1)
 from accounts
```

Comment: Use backticks to escape alias names with special characters

Comment: Note that SQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. I don't see too much of that here.

Comment: month(curdate()) as monthname(curdate()) makes no sense what are you trying to do

Comment: i am trying to create a view with column names as the date for that range.  so for january 2019 the values will be 29999.56 but the column name must be concat(monthname(curdate()),' ',year(2019) ="january 2019" then december 2018 values is 343234 and column name must be concat(monthname(datesub(curdate(),interval 1 month)),' ',datesub(curdate(curdate(),inertval 1 year) = December 2018.

this way it will automaticaall move over to new month when new month starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you seem to want is this months number and name and last months number and name so

```
select month(curdate()), monthname(curdate()),
          month(curdate()) - 1, 
            monthname(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month));

+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| month(curdate()) | monthname(curdate()) | month(curdate()) - 1 | monthname(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)) |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|               12 | December             |                   11 | November                                         |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I dont think you understand the question. the column names should be the result.Select sum(totaljan) as monthname(curdate()),
         sum(febtotal) as      monthname(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month));
+-------------=+------------+
December - January
215           -  315

Comment: I dont think you understand the question. the column names should be the result.Select sum(totaljan) as monthname(curdate()),
         sum(febtotal) as      monthname(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month));
+---------------+------------+
|December   | January  |
+                  +              +
|215              |  315       |
+---------------+------------+

Answer (score 0):

Well here you go.

```
SET @curdate = CURDATE();
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id AS"', MONTHNAME(@curdate), '"FROM accounts limit 
1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```